# I this the correct approach?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to make sure I'm thinking about this question right.
Ten students are traveling home from college. Amoung them they have two cars, each of which will hold six passengers. How many ways can they distribute themselves in the two cars?
My solution:
$$ {10 \choose 6,4} = \frac{10!}{6!4!}=210$$
my reasoning is that there are 10 people we would like to place in 2 cars so that 6 are in the first car and 4 are in the second.

Comment: or $$ {10 \choose 6,4} + {10\choose 5} = 462 $$

Answer (score 0):

$1.$ We assume the cars are distinct. Call them A and B. We need to choose $4$, $5$, or $6$ students for Car A. The number of choices is $\binom{10}{4}+\binom{10}{5}+\binom{10}{6}$.

$2.$ If the cars are not distinct, things get more interesting. The split can be $5$-$5$ or $4$-$6$.

The $4$-$6$ split is easy, we choose $4$ people. The $5$-$5$ is more subtle, since $\binom{10}{5}$ double-counts these.

Comment: nothing is different about the cars, each car can fit a most 6 students

Comment: Why wouldn't I count the 6-4 split twice along with 5-5 split?

Comment: $$ 2*{10 \choose 6,4} + 2*{10\choose 5} = 924 $$

Comment: If the cars are identical, it is $\binom{10}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot \binom{10}{5}$. From the wording of the problem, it is not clear whether they are to be viewed as identical. They have identical capacities, but to me it might make a difference whether I travel in the Rolls-Royce or the Hyundai.

Comment: Its also weird cause it doesn't tell whether it matters if who drives too, since the cars are owned by two of the 10 people

Comment: $$ 2*{10 \choose 6,4} + {10\choose 5} = 672 $$. I think this will cover {{4 car A, 6 car B},{6 car A , 4 car B},{5 car A, 5 car B}}